# Method does not change the value of object if the object is in a slice

Tags: pointers, for-loop, go, struct, slice

Here is my program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Number struct {
    val int
}

func (num * Number) Increment () {
    num.val += 1
}

func (num Number) Value() int {
    return num.val
}

func main() {
    numbers := []Number {
        {val: 12}, 
        {val: 7},
        {val: 0},
    }

    for _, each := range numbers {
        each.Increment()
        fmt.Println(each.Value())
    }

    for _, each := range numbers {
        fmt.Println(each.Value())
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
13
8
1
12
7
0
```

First question: why does the `Increment()`method not update the value in the first for loop? I used pointer as the receiver so that `val` can be updated for sure, but why would the second `for` loop print out the original values of those `Number`s?

Second question: what can be done so that when I iterate over a slice of `Number`s and invoke the `Increment()` method, all `Number`s are correctly incremented?

**[Edit]** I noticed that if I use index-based `for` loop and invoke the `Increment()` method, values will be correctly updated. Why?

```
for i := 0; i < len(numbers); i++ {
    numbers[i].Increment()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `for range` loop:

```
for _, each := range numbers {
```

iterates over the elements of the `numbers` slice, and in each iteration it assigns (**copies**) an element to the `each` loop variable.

Since your `numbers` slices is of type `[]Number`, it will copy the `Number` struct into the `each` variable (whose type will be `Number`).

Then you call the `Number.Increment()` method on this variable. Since `Increment()` has pointer receiver, this is a shorthand for `(&each).Increment()`. So the address of this loop variable is taken and used as the receiver for the `Increment()` method. The `Increment()` method will properly change this loop variable, but this is independent, distinct, detached from the slice, so you are not modifying the element in the slice.

When you do:

```
for i := 0; i < len(numbers); i++ {
    numbers[i].Increment()
}
```

Elements of `numbers` are not copied here. This:

```
numbers[i].Increment()
```

Indexes the `numbers` slice, and since `Increment()` has a pointer receiver, the address of `numbers[i]` is taken and used, which is the address of the element **in the slice**. So here, you will modify the `Number` struct value of the slice.

Note that you can also use `for range` here:

```
for i := range numbers {
    numbers[i].Increment()
}
```

The first iteration variable when ranging over a slice is the index.

Also, if you would store pointers in your `numbers` slice (which would then have type of `[]*Number`), the same thing would happen, but in that case the `for range` would copy pointers, not structs, and the pointer in the loop variable would point to the same `Number` struct value as the pointer in the slice would, so that would also work with your first `for range` variant.

All these are detailed in [Spec: For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements), in the *For statements with range clause* subsection.

Answer (score 1):

In your original version, the loop variable `each` is a copy of the `Number` struct. Notice that it is not a pointer to it, nor is it the copy of a pointer to it. That means, that there is a newly created `Number` in each iteration. You call a method on a pointer to this newly created instance, then it gets destroyed after the loop and your original data has not changed.

If you would instead use `numbers := []*Number { ...` and iterate over that, the `each` variable would be the copy of a pointer to `Number`. Using copies of pointers is the same as using pointers, because the copy points to the same memory location, thus if you then call the method, the data in the slice wil change.

For your edit: if you use `numbers[i]` then you reference the data inside the slice, obviously. As I stated above, the `for range` loop will create a copy of the items in its `each` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you loop through the slice it creates a copy of original variable which is used as value and is incremented. But when you are using the `index` you are pointing to the value backed at that address which is than incremented and hence original value got changed.

Print the value of both variable to see the changes as:

```
for i, each := range numbers {
    each.Increment()
    fmt.Println(each, numbers[i])
}
```

you can also print the address of variable in a loop with the original value address to see that both variables have different address. Hence you are actually creating a local variable when iterating over `numbers`.

```
for i, each := range numbers {
    each.Increment()
    fmt.Printf("%p -- %p\n",&each, &numbers[i])
}
```

Working Code to check address on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/no330mQlgGM)