# Slice element not updated in go

Tags: go, pointers, slice

I have an account struct as below:

```golang
type Account struct {
    Id       string
    Name     string
    Address  string
    City     string
    Email    string
    Phone    string
    Username string
    Password string
    IsActive bool
}
```

I also have two function: `find` and `update`. The `find` function find certain element from the slice and return the pointer to the element:

```golang
func find(accounts []Account, username string) *Account {
    for _, acc := range accounts {
        if acc.IsActive && acc.Username == username {
            return &acc
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The update function change certain field from the params:

```golang
func update(account *Account, name string) {
    account.Name = name
}
```

In `main`, i try to `find` an element from the slice and store it to a pointer of account. Then, i try to `update` a field in the next line. This is how my `main` looks like:

```golang
func main() {
    accounts := []Account{{
        Id:       "1",
        Name:     "name",
        Address:  "address",
        City:     "city",
        Email:    "email@email.com",
        Phone:    "123456789",
        Username: "username",
        Password: "1234",
        IsActive: true,
    }}
    var acc *Account
    acc = find(accounts, "username")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", accounts)
    fmt.Println(acc)

    update(acc, "updated")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", accounts)
    fmt.Println(acc)
}
```

The problem is when `update` called, the element in slice is not updated. It just update the data of stored account. Below is the output of main:

```
// find
[{1 name address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}]
&{1 name address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}

// update
[{1 name address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}]
&{1 updated address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}
```

How to make the element inside the slice updated when the store element changed? Thank you for your help, any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: You're not updating the slice, you're updating a copy of one of the slice elements.

Comment: Does [Method does not change the value of object if the object is in a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493190/5728991) answer your question?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue is you are returning copy of element rather than actual address of the element in the array

```
return &acc
```

change your find function as below

```
func find(accounts []Account, username string) *Account {
for idx , acc := range accounts {
    if acc.IsActive && acc.Username == username {
        return &accounts[idx]
    }
}
return nil
}
```

your will get the expected response

```
[{1 name address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}]
&{1 name address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}
[{1 updated address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}]
&{1 updated address city email@email.com 123456789 username 1234 true}
```

you can check the updated code [here in go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-nQQPpdI8gB)

Comment: consider this code will run into weird behavior if the slice backing array is updated and that you keep trying to update the pointer.